# Getting value of element which is deep inside other elements

Tags: jquery, html, dom, element

I've got

```
<div class='test1'>
    <div>..</div>
    <div>
        <span>...</span>
        <span>target info</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get Target info from that span if I know only test1 class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your HTML is fixed as show**

To get the value of `span` you can use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as follow.

`eq(1)` will get you the second element and `text` will give the innerText of element.

```js
alert($('.test1 div').eq(1).find('span').eq(1).text());
// Get the second span from second div inside .test1 class element
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test1'>
  <div>..</div>
  <div>
    <span>...</span>
    <span>target info</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that went to div which is after test1, but my span is in second div

Comment: I mean there is test1 div, and 2 divs inside. my target is in second div which is inside test1

Comment: @David Updated accordingly. Please check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var textOfLastSpan = $('.test1').find('span').last().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try `$(".test1 span:eq(1)").text();`